# Speed issues when converting list to dictionary

Tags: python, performance

I'm having some speed issues regarding the conversion of lists to dictionaries, where the following operation takes up about 90% of the total running time:

```
def list2dict(list_):
    return_dict = {}

    for idx, word in enumerate(list_):
        if word in return_dict:
            raise ValueError("duplicate string found in list: %s" % (word))
        return_dict[word] = idx

    return return_dict
```

I'm having troubles seeing what it is exactly that causes this. Are there any obvious bottlenecks that you see in the code, or suggestions on how to speed it up?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the cost of converting less than the cost of using `list.index(item)` whenever you need? You could make your code a little faster by ditching the duplicate check, and adding a check at the end that both list and dictionary have the same `len()` (at the expense of a less helpful error).

Comment: From @adsmith's answer, it looks like there's not terribly much performance improvement to squeeze out of this (maybe 15%) by modifying the function itself.  What's the data you are interrogating here?  There might be a way to track or injest it that would be more efficient than your current list-based solution.

Comment: Also, another important question here is if the exception path is a condition you expect to encounter often.

Comment: Why does this take such a big fraction of your runtime? Are you calling it too often? What are you using the dict for? How did you profile your code? (You're not doing something silly like `list2dict(l)[word]`, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Figured I'd put this up top since it's bigger -- turns out that a minor tweak to OP's code gives a pretty big bump in performance.

```
def list2dict(list_):    # OLD
    return_dict = {}
    for idx, word in enumerate(list_):
        if word in return_dict: # this compare is happening every iteration!
            raise ValueError("duplicate string found in list: %s" % (word))
        return_dict[word] = idx
    return return_dict

def list2dictNEW(list_): #NEW HOTNESS
    return_dict = {}
    for idx, word in enumerate(list_):
        return_dict[word] = idx # overwrite if you want to, because...
    if len(return_dict) == len(list_): return return_dict
    # if the lengths aren't the same, something got overwritten so we
    # won't return. If they ARE the same, toss it back with only one
    # compare (rather than n compares in the original
    else: raise ValueError("There were duplicates in list {}".format(list_))

DEMO:
>>> timeit(lambda: list2dictNEW(TEST))
1.9117132451798682
>>> timeit(lambda: list2dict(TEST)):
2.2543816669587216
# gains of a third of a second per million iterations!
# that's a 15.2% speed bost
```

No obvious answers, but you could try something like:

```
def list2dict(list_):
    return_dict = dict()
    for idx,word in enumerate(list_):
        return_dict.setdefault(word,idx)
    return return_dict
```

You could also build a set and do `list.index` since you say the lists are fairly small, but I'm GUESSING that would be slower rather than faster. This would need profiling to be sure (use `timeit.timeit`)

```
def list2dict(list_):
    set_ = set(list_)
    return {word:list_.index(word) for word in set_}
```

I took the liberty of running some profiles on a set of test data. Here are the results:

```
TEST = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'] # 10 items

def list2dictA(list_): # build set and index word
    set_ = set(list_)
    return {word:list_.index(word) for word in set_}

def list2dictB(list_): # setdefault over enumerate(list)
    return_dict = dict()
    for idx,word in enumerate(list_):
        return_dict.setdefault(word,idx)
    return return_dict

def list2dictC(list_): # dict comp over enumerate(list)
    return_dict = {word:idx for idx,word in enumerate(list_)}
    if len(return_dict) == len(list_):
        return return_dict
    else:
        raise ValueError("Duplicate string found in list")

def list2dictD(list_): # Original example from Question
    return_dict = {}
    for idx, word in enumerate(list_):
        if word in return_dict:
            raise ValueError("duplicate string found in list: %s" % (word))
        return_dict[word] = idx
    return return_dict

>>> timeit(lambda: list2dictA(TEST))
5.336584700190931
>>> timeit(lambda: list2dictB(TEST))
2.7587691306531
>>> timeit(lambda: list2dictC(TEST))
2.1609074989233292
>>> timeit(lambda: list2dictD(TEST))
2.2543816669587216
```

Comment: `index` is O(n), which is going to translate to n*n/2 to discover the indexes for this algorithm.  I'm pretty sure you'd be better off running the dict comprehension over `enumerate(list_)`, which should make it just n instead of n*n/2.  Checking `len(dict_) == len(list_)` after the fact will be faster, granted it won't give you the repeated value.  Though since that's an exception condition anyway, you can probably afford to be inefficient for the sake of a better error there and just use a `Counter` if the `len` check fails.

Comment: @SilasRay Big O isn't really a factor here with his lists being so small. The constants at play are going to be a much bigger contributor to time-spent (compared to usual) than the scalars. That's why I noted that he should profile it.

Comment: @SilasRay that said, running a dict comp on `enumerate(list_)` may be faster anyhow. I'm not sure how fast `enumerate` builds.

Comment: Given OP said the list is 10 elements long, the second function iterates effectively the entire list (in the case that it is all uniques) 2+n*n/2, or 52, times.  The `enumerate` inside a dict comp method would iterate the sequence once.

Comment: @SilasRay I understand what you're saying, my point was that iterating the entire list 52 times may be cheaper than building a new list after iterating it once. It's not, in fact it's massively slower, but I didn't know that until profiling. See my edit.

Comment: Actually, another one that would be interesting would be `list2dictD` except without the short circuit condition in the insertion loop.  That might be a wash with the `enumerate` version, which would be interesting information on it's own (essentially, showing the dict comps aren't better in terms of performance than iterative insertion).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48526/discussion-between-adsmith-and-silas-ray)

Comment: For the record, +1 for all the effort you put in to this answer, and the good information you got out.  :)

Comment: none of your methods follow the original function ~ they don't return what the duplicate entry was.

Comment: @blakev since that's an implementation detail raising an exception, and indeed merely the MESSAGE in the exception, I didn't try to keep that feature. If I had, the function would be MASSIVELY slower.

Comment: @blakev indeed, your own solution is 4 times slower than the original function because it tries to build this list THEN iterate through the list THEN build a dict based on that iteration. If OP needs that particular feature, then his solution is the best way to do that.

Comment: Back to the solution, I just thought of something that might potentially gain another very small performance edge.  Instead of using `len(list_)` which means a function look up in global scope along with a function call and object attribute lookup, just reference the local variable `idx + 1`.  It should be the last index of the list after exiting the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest function depends on the length of `list_`. [adsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adsmith)'s `list2dictC()` is pretty fast for small lists (less than ~80 items). But when the list size grow I find my `list2dictE()` about 8% faster.

```
def list2dictC(list_):  # dict comp over enumerate(list)
    return_dict = {word: idx for idx, word in enumerate(list_)}
    if len(return_dict) == len(list_):
        return return_dict
    else:
        raise ValueError("Duplicate string found in list")

def list2dictE(list_):  # Faster for lists with ~80 items or more
    l = len(list_)
    return_dict = dict(zip(list_, range(l)))
    if len(return_dict) == l:
        return return_dict
    else:
        raise ValueError("Duplicate string found in list")
```

If the length is known to be small keep it's of no use, but if it's not the case maybe add something like `l = len(list_); if l < 80: ... else: ...`. It's just an additional if statement since both functions need to know the list length anyways.  The threshold of 80 items may very depending on your setup, but it's in that bollpark for me both for python 2.7 and 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
def l2d(list_):
    dupes = set(filter(lambda x: a.count(x) > 1, a))
    if len(dupes) > 0:
        raise ValueError('duplicates: %s' % (dupes))
    return dict((word, idx) for (idx, word) in enumerate(list_))
```

How does this compare?

Comment: `timeit` runs it a million times in `9.243808421117365` seconds. See my answer for other examples.

Comment: Given that the first line is already `O(n^2)`, I doubt this would fare well against other options...

Comment: This returns all the duplicate entries ... I don't know how important duplicates are, but if he has multiple duplicates his operation time will be whatever `O(*) * duplicate_entries` is plus all the overhead of raising each error.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas seems to speed it up by a third, though as said it's already possibly "fast enough"

```
> TEST = # english scrabble dictionary, 83882 entries
> def mylist2dict(list_):
      return_dict = pd.Series(index=list_, data=np.arange(len(list_)))
      if not return_dict.index.is_unique:
          raise ValueError
      return return_dict
> %timeit list2dict(TEST)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ms per loop
> %timeit mylist2dict(TEST)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This came in at avg 2.36 µs per run. Because the OPs code looked like it was favoring the first incident of a value I reversed the range so that it doesn't need any logic to check for the existence of values.

```
def mkdct(dct):
    l = len(dct-1)
    return {dct[x]:(l-x) for x in range(len(dct), -1, -1)}
```

Edit: there were some dumb mistakes there.